# Accordion not working

Tags: lightning, accordion

Here i write a code for mobile view but for mobile only spinner is moving they will not showing anything. Meanwhile for desktop it is working fine why?

```
<template>
    <template if:true={spinner}>
        <lightning-spinner variant="brand" size="large" title="Processing..">
            <span> Please do not click back button </span>
        </lightning-spinner>
    </template>
    <template if:false={spinner}>

        <div>
            <h1 class="headercolor"> <span>MY CONTRACTS</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds_p_arround" if:false={isMobile}>
            <div class="slot">
                <div class="slot-body">
                    <template if:false={hasNoContracts}>
                        <table data-id="OpportunityTable" class="customers">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-value="Number">Contract Number</th>
                                    <th data-value="GymnastName">Gymnast Name</th>
                                    <th data-value="ScheduleGname">Class Schedule</th>
                                    <th data-value="CreatedDate">Created Date</th>
                                    <th data-value="ExpiryDate">Paid Amount</th>
                                    <!-- <th data-value="Amount">Amount</th> -->
                                    <th data-value="Status">Status</th>
                                    <th data-value="Click here">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <template for:each={contractDetails} for:item="contractDetail" for:index="index">
                                    <tr key={contractDetail.Id} data-key={contractDetail.Id} data-scope="row">
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="white-space: normal;" class="slds-truncate"
                                                title={contractDetail.sContractNumber}>
                                                {contractDetail.sContractNumber}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td title={contractDetail.sGymnastName}>{contractDetail.sGymnastName}</td>
                                        <td title={contractDetail.sScheduleGName}>{contractDetail.sScheduleGName}</td>
                                        <td title={contractDetail.dCreatedDate}>{contractDetail.dCreatedDate}</td>
                                        <td title={contractDetail.dExpiryDate}>{contractDetail.dPaidAmount}</td>
                                        <!-- <td title={contractDetail.dAmount}>{contractDetail.dAmount}</td> -->
                                        <td title={contractDetail.sStatus}>{contractDetail.sStatus}</td>
                                        <template if:true={contractDetail.bShowClickHereEnabled}>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="javascript:void();" data-tras-id={contractDetail.sId} onclick={openContract}>Click Here</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </template>
                                        <template if:true={contractDetail.bShowView}>
                                            <td >
                                                <a href={contractDetail.sContractLinkView} target="_blank">View</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </template>
                                        <template if:true={contractDetail.bShowClickHereDisabled}>
                                            <td >
                                                <span class="disabledLink">Click Here</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </template>

                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </template>
                    <template if:true={hasNoContracts}>
                        <h1> <span style="color: red">NO CONTRACTS AVAILABLE</span></h1>
                        
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div if:true={isMobile}>
            <template if:false={hasNoContracts}>
            <lightning-accordion class="example-accordion"
                                onsectiontoggle={handleToggleSection}
                                active-section-name={activeSections}
                                style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
                                <template for:each={contractDetails} for:item="contractDetail" for:index="index">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label={contractDetail.sContractNumber} key={record.Id} >
                        <table data-id="OpportunityTable" class="innerTable">
                        
                        <tr><th data-value="Number">Class</th>
                            <td>
                                {contractDetail.sContractNumber}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template>
            
            </lightning-accordion>
        </template>
        </div>
        
    </template>

</template>
```

Javascript Controller:

```
retrieveContractDetails(parentId){
    getContractDetails({
        sPrimaryContactId:parentId
    })
    .then(result => {
        if(result){
            console.log('result == > '+JSON.stringify(result));
            for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                let obj = result[i];
                obj.dCreatedDate = this.convertDateFormat(obj.dCreatedDate);
                obj.dExpiryDate = this.convertDateFormat(obj.dExpiryDate);
            }
            this.spinner = false;
            this.contractDetails = result;
            if(this.contractDetails.length>0){
                this.hasNoContracts=false;
            }
            else{
                this.hasNoContracts=true;
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Get class Error ', error);
        this.spinner = false;
        this.hasNoContracts=true;
        showToast(this,'Error while retieving contracts','error','Error')
    });
}
```

Comment: Without your JavaScript, I'm not sure we could tell. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I'll add my JS in the code

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide any error details (which you can normally get by checking the console), Here are some of the things that you should check:

- Do you know if `isMobile` is true?
- Is `activeSections` initialized?
- Is `result` an Array?
- Are you trapping errors in `convertDateFormat`?
- Have you tried removing `convertDateFormat` to see if that helps things?
- Have you initialized the accordion correctly? Have you tried initializing it with some static data to see if renders anything?
- Note that that the main difference between Mobile and Desktop views is the presence of the accordion - this means that you are likely causing it to error. This is probably the most important thing to check. Get the accordion working and you will get it all all working.